# Deploying ASP.Net MVC 2.0 application IIS 7.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7

I am trying whole day for this issue. I just created a test ASP.Net MVC 2.0 application and trying to deploy it in IIS and access it. In VS 2010 it works fine. I just created a default application. No changes are done.I published it and then created a virtual directory in IIS and map the path to published path. When I try to brouse it, it gives error below. I am using .Net 4.0 and set the default App Pool in .Net 4.0 version and set as System.Web.MVC property of set Local to true. Appreciate your help on it.

HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error
Handler "PageHandlerFactory-Integrated" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list Detailed Error Information
Module IIS Web Core 
Notification ExecuteRequestHandler 
Handler PageHandlerFactory-Integrated 
Error Code 0x8007000d 
Requested URL http://localhost:80/TestSite/default.aspx 
Physical Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test\default.aspx 
Logon Method Anonymous 
Logon User Anonymous

Answer (score 2):

This is a few month ago, but this is a Q & A site and appearently 70 peoples visit this question so far.

My idea to solve it is based on the IIS7 / .NET4 installation itself.

Message:

```
Handler “PageHandlerFactory-Integrated” has a bad module “ManagedPipelineHandler”
```

It appears to me that some installation processess does not register .NET into IIS.that

```
C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

May help you out. The path the the aspnet_regiis can be different based to your version of .NET. In case of that, just browse to the corresponding map from within Framework/?

Unregister with `-u` instead od `-i` at the end (if wanted to..),